# Should an exception be thrown when the data from db is bad?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-access-layer

In this particular application, there is no separate data layer and the data access code is in the Entity itself. For example, consider a Customer entity, then in the Customer.cs file where the members and properties are defined, you have methods to load the Customer object as below

```
public bool TryLoad(int customerID, out Customer customer)
{
    bool success = false
    try
    {
        //code which calls the db and fills a SqlDataReader
        ReadDataFromSqlDataReader(reader);
        success = true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)  
    {
      LogError();
      success = false;
    }
    return success;
}
```

Now, in the ReadDataFromSqlDataReader(reader), tryparse is used to load data from the reader into the object. e.g.

```
public void ReadDataFromSqlDataReader(reader)
{
   int.TryParse(reader["CustomerID"].ToString(), out this.CustomerID);
   PhoneNumber.TryParse(reader["PhoneNumber"].ToString(), out this.PhoneNumber);
   ... similar TryParse code for all the other fields..
}
```

Is using TryParse to read all the properties from the reader a good practise? A dev told me that its done this way as TryParse has a better performance than int.Parse. But wouldnt you want an exception to be throw when the value you are reading from the db does not conform to what your code expects? I mean in this case, if there is a wrong phone number in the db then perhaps the object shouldn't be initialized at all instead of loading an object with an empty phone number?

Comment: sounds exceptional to me

Comment: `TryParse` only has better performance of `Parse` if you're looking to deal with bad data.

Comment: I can't imagine performance is any different. It swallows the exception so in effect contains the same code you would write on the outside using .Parse anyway.

Comment: A parse will only fail if you are trying to convert the database data to an incompatible type, right. Although I guess there aren't many databases with a native `PhoneNumber` type

Comment: As, `TryParse` returns Boolean value. So, I can `ByPass/Continue` the `Upcoming Logic/Any Database` request on the  basis of `Boolean` Value. I will not let the exception to occur in such scenaria. For that I will do the logging etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, following the *fail-fast* principle, you would want an exception to be thrown the moment a value comes back that cannot be converted into the expected type.

If one of these operations fails and you continue as if nothing happened, you are likely to get weird errors that are hard to catch and hard to pinpoint: objects being added to the database when they should have been updating an existing row, data mysteriously disappearing, dogs and cats living together... you get the idea.

On the other hand, if you throw an exception immediately, you know exactly where your problem is and you can catch it and fix it before it becomes worse.

`TryParse` will work faster than `Parse` in case of failure simply because it doesn't have to throw an exception (which can be expensive), but if you're assuming that things will succeed (which this code is doing by not using the result of the parse), you should get equivalent performance using `Parse`.

Comment: As, `TryParse` returns Boolean value. So, I can `ByPass/Continue` the `Upcoming Logic/Any Database` request on the  basis of `Boolean` Value. I will not let the exception to occur in such scenaria. For that I will do the logging etc.

Answer (score 1):

What sort of validation are  you doing when the data is being inserted and/or updated?

As long as you are applying some form of validation here, I personally would not be validating the data coming out of the Database as you should be confident that you are only putting in valid data.

Comment: Can you 100% guarantee that it is always going to be good data?  What happens when the dba opens the table directly and enters "stjkerij" for a phone number?

Comment: The problem is that there was no validation initially when the system was developed. For example, PhoneNumber was not a type defined in the code and was basically a string. After a few years, one of the devs defined PhoneNumber as a type and now mostly whenever data is inserted , it is valid data. But the mess that is the old code, I cannot be 100% sure that the data that is coming from the db is always valid. Also, if I fail and log these, I might actually be able to weed out bad data from the database.

Comment: @JonH, doesn't matter whether the data is good, what matters is can you sensiblyt make it good, if it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Effective validation be performed when data is inserted into the database. It's not a good design with which bad data could be entered in the database. If database contains bad phone number, user should be asked to enter phone number again if its mandatory and if phone number is not that important, you could initialize phone number to null in case of bad data.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be using TryParse for that.
If my db had rubbish in it, I'd want that addressed.
If the data was ambiguous in terms of parsing (e.g. Varchar with int or double in it as a string)
I'd want to sort out my schema, TryParse as type detection would be a quick and simple hack.

Answer (score 0):

If you would handle it, well yes you should throw an exception. But if you don't care about the exception and if you would filter the right data and use it (in this case non zeros) you can skip.

Comment: I heartily disagree. Programmers calling this method are going to assume that the objects they get are fully populated. Giving them an object that is not fully populated is asking for trouble. Even if there is no handling code, it's better for the system to fail spectacularly and bring your attention to the fact that you have a bug than to allow the rest of your code to consume this data as if nothing is wrong.

Comment: You are right but it is an option. Throwing or not throwing exceptions depends on what you are trying to do. I said if you care you should throw an exception but that may not be the case all the time. Maybe he wants to display a message in the Phone Number column in the user interface like "Your phone number is not valid.".

Comment: If I was doing that and it not being valid was an exception. I'd throw it and trap it in the caller, and deal with it in the calling code. (or mabe trap and raise a custom exception. Putting the message inside the code doing the parse, means it's doing more than one thing, means you have to do the same thing or break DRY, and will lead to a bad design, and make any unit tests surrounding UI dependant. So an option yes, a good one I'm dubious.

Comment: Catching every exception (say 1000 items) and handling may be overkill other than assigning a simple string to an object's field. So there is no best in a general sense, there is best in terms of performance, design, testability and so on.

Comment: It's all relative, but if a 1000 records was a significant %age the total I'd fix the data and justify doing so based on the performance gain. If you have to live with it you have to, got to make sure it's pretty much your only alternative, bad designs can become a bad habit.

Comment: Being purist can lead to impractical. Anyway, an idea is never bad.

Answer (score 0):

As, `TryParse` returns Boolean value. So, I can `ByPass/Continue` the `Upcoming Logic/Any Database` request on the  basis of `Boolean` Value. I will not let the exception to occur in such scenaria. For that I will do the logging etc.

**Parse**

> 1. Throws an exception.
> 2. Use it if you are sure the value will be valid

**TryParse**

> 1. Returns a bool indicating whether it succeeded
> 2. It just try/catch internally that why is implemented without exceptions so that it is fast
> 3. Use it in case the value may be InValid